# Visual studio 2015 can not run ADB: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova

I'm trying to build and run Cordova application on visual studio but unfortunately I can not run it directly on my android device,
 As you can see in the attached picture it build correctly I can install it manually it work just fine but not directly from VS.

Any Ideas?

picture [image: picture]

Comment: you can try to add full path to adb executable to PATH system environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Android SDK path in System environment variables PATH e.g `C:\ANDROID_SDK\platform-tools` and restart your Computer.